# Is there a way i can import users having profile2 with feeds

Tags: feeds, users, migrations

I have done user migration using feeds. but i am not able to migrate the profile2 fields with it. Is there a way? am I missing something. I am trying to use migrate module but its tricky. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: I was able to do this by using migrate module. I had to migrate the profile fields.

Answer (score 1):

There's a module called [Feeds Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_profile2) which extends the built-in User processor so that Profile2 profiles can be created and updated as part of a user importer.